# How do I make a database backup and have it stored locally?

Tags: database, backup, roundhouse

So here's the challenge. I need to use C# to back up a database locally from a remote database server and the only share we have is \\computer\c$.

If the answer is to back up to a location on the remote database server and then copy that local, assume there is not a share on the remote location.  Just b/c I have access to the database does not mean I have access to the file system.

This Q/A looks close to what I want, but remember the regular account in the database will not have access to the network. [Sample sql script to zip and transfer database backup file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128166/sample-sql-script-to-zip-and-transfer-database-backup-file)

With all of that in mind...anyone done something like this and care to share? Or have an idea of how to do this?

UPDATE: I was being vague on purpose.  The context here is this:

1. I do not have access to files on the server where the database is.
2. I am running the C# from the client under the client's credentials, so I have full control of the client computer and can do anything in this domain.

I think I actually have figured out what we are going to do though:

1. Create a special folder in the AppData area of the current user.
2. Create a fileshare to that folder
3. Add rights to Everyone for that particular share and folder.
4. Process the backup based on that share.
5. Remove the share and reset the permissions.

In case anyone is curious what this question refers to: [RoundhousE](http://code.google.com/p/roundhouse/issues/detail?id=3)

Comment: You're getting a certain amount of grief you may not deserve - you need to provide a bit more context about why you can't get at the database you need to back up.

Comment: Thanks man. I will be less vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think I actually have figured out what we are going to do:

1. Create a special folder in the AppData area of the current user.
2. Create a fileshare to that folder
3. Add rights to Everyone for that particular share and folder.
4. Process the backup based on that share.
5. Remove the share and reset the permissions.

In case anyone is curious what this question refers to: [RoundhousE](http://code.google.com/p/roundhouse/issues/detail?id=3)

Answer (score 1):

Context?  Oracle?  MySQL?  SQL Server?  Db Size?  Backup time?  Availability requirements?  Encryption requirements?  Rowcount validation?

I'm guessing you're talking about SQL Server, based on the TSQL example- to which I'd recommend checking out DMO objects.  Here's a primer- http://www.codersource.net/csharp_sqldmo_sqlserver.aspx.

Truthfully- the vague nature of your question- and the fact that it's context free gives me some heebie jeebies.  Be sure to test in a test envrionment and not run on production data, ok?

Answer (score 1):

The backup system of SQL Server runs the entire backup procedure *on the server*, which basically means that the file has to be put somewhere the database server can put it and has access to.

In other words, the file *will be written from the server*.

If you:

1. Cannot access files directly on the server, from the client, in any way
2. Cannot download files from the server, to the client, in any way
3. Cannot write files from the server, to a common place, that is reachable by the client in any way

Then you are left with one way: Reimplement backup.

If your actual question is this:

> With all of that in mind...anyone done something like this and care to share?

Then I'm going to hazard a guess that the answer to this question is: **No**.

Are you *sure* you cannot change the problem to one that is solvable?

Comment: I actually think I might have it figured out.  http://code.google.com/p/roundhouse/issues/detail?id=3

Answer (score -1):

If you want/need to back up a database, then in general, for the purpose of guaranteed database consistency, the database server will need to be either completely shut down, or at least be completely in read-only mode.

Your question sounds like your "challengers" have taken you to task to back up a remote server while none of those conditions are satisfied.  The only sensible answer to such a challenge is that it cannot be done.

Comment: Most database engines today allows for a hot backup which will be consistent.

Comment: If the OP has the "hotbackup" facility of his DBMS to his avail, then he wouldn't have had to ask the question.

Once again a moronic downvote by an idiot who doesn't bother to read the question (the keyword was "remote"), nor to think about the answer.

thanksalot.

Comment: OH, and I almost forgot the other keyword, "backup remote server, [backup] STORED LOCALLY".

Comment: I didn't vote you down... but to be clear, I want to do an automated database backup from a remote server and don't have access to the remote file system. I would like to have the backup be stored locally. I don't want the .mdf file, I want the .bak (think SQL server for now).